# Making a triangulated sphere

Tags: geometry

I want to create a triangulated 1.2756m diameter sphere from 100mm thick hi-density foam. I won't use a cnc router or anything like that, I'll cut triangles with a fine-tooth Japanese pull saw and chamfer the edges so that the foam triangles can be glued together to make a triangulated sphere,

[triangulated sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSuIQ.png)

then I'll smooth down the vertices (the pointy bits) and, hopefully, end up with a perfect, hollow sphere on to which I can stick the 12 gores (the banana-peel-shaped sections of a map) on to.

First, I need to know how many triangles I need to cut and what the length of the edges should be.

Second, I need to know how to join the individual triangles together. The triangles will be of different sizes so I can't just glue them together willy nilly. There needs to be some sort of order, and this, I don't understand.

Why a 1.2756m diameter? Because the Earth diameter is 12,756km in diameter so the globe I'm making will be 1:10 million scale.

I'm new to this mathematics malarkey and I'd be grateful for easily-comprehensible answers to this request for assistance. Thanks!

Comment: If you don’t want to do any “mathematics malarkey” (sic), then I suggest getting a decent 3D CAD system, which will do it for you. There are free ones available, like FreeCAD or Fusion360.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_polyhedron

Comment: The number of triangles needed depends on how closely you want approximate the sphere (I.e. how much sanding of the pointy bits you’re willing to do). The minimum number of triangles is 4. This will give you a tetrahedron, and a lot of sanding. A better option is probably 20 triangles forming an icosahedron. All the triangles are the same size and shape, so the ordering problem that you mentioned does not arise.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularIcosahedron.html

Comment: https://archive.bridgesmathart.org/2022/bridges2022-41.pdf

Comment: Taking a icosahedron as suggested by Bubba is a good idea. For a slightly finer subdivision, one can also consider using the [fullerene shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckminsterfullerene) which results from the truncation of a icosahedron, with pentagons and hexagons all of the same size ; generalization : "Johnson solids".

Comment: Sorry, an error of mine : not "Johnson solids" but "Goldberg polyhedra" (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_polyhedron))